# Have ticks at edges of bins (instead of center) with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm

I have the following R data frame `nPhotosClassified`:

```
> glimpse(nPhotosClassified)
Observations: 236
Variables: 2
$ person_id         <int> 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 194, 195, 199...
$ nPhotosClassified <int> 113, 164, 2126, 637, 75, 16, 161, 29, 15, 6338, 596, 18, 14, 63, 36777, 19117, 5625...
```

With it I tried to make a `geom_histogram` of the `nPhotosClassified` variable with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data = nPhotosClassified, mapping = aes(x = nPhotosClassified)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 10) + 
    scale_x_log10(name = "Number of photos classified",
                  breaks = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000)) + 
    ylab(label = "Number of users") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 100, colour = "red") +
    theme(# This gets rid of the whole border around the plot, but also makes
          # the axes disappear:
          panel.border = element_blank(), 
          # So manually add lines for the axes back:
          axis.line = element_line())
```

Which gives me this result:

[image]

For this question, I've added a red vertical line to indicate that the major tick marks fall on the center of these bins.

**Question:** How do I adjust the bins (or the tick marks???) so that all the tick marks fall on the edge of bins rather than in the middle of them?

For example, how do I end up with two bins between 1 and 10, two bins between 10 and 100, and so on? Please note that I want my x-axis to be on the log10 scale.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Here is the full dataset:

```
> dput(nPhotosClassified)
structure(list(person_id = c(179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 
185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 194L, 195L, 199L, 
201L, 204L, 205L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
216L, 217L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 
228L, 229L, 230L, 234L, 235L, 237L, 238L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 246L, 
249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 255L, 256L, 259L, 261L, 264L, 265L, 
266L, 267L, 268L, 271L, 272L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 281L, 
282L, 283L, 285L, 294L, 296L, 298L, 299L, 302L, 304L, 305L, 307L, 
309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 323L, 325L, 326L, 
327L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 335L, 341L, 344L, 347L, 348L, 363L, 367L, 
375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 386L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 
399L, 401L, 402L, 404L, 406L, 407L, 409L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 
419L, 421L, 425L, 426L, 428L, 429L, 432L, 433L, 440L, 441L, 445L, 
448L, 452L, 456L, 461L, 462L, 464L, 468L, 471L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 
478L, 483L, 486L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 497L, 498L, 501L, 
502L, 505L, 509L, 512L, 518L, 520L, 532L, 533L, 535L, 537L, 539L, 
540L, 543L, 544L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 554L, 562L, 564L, 581L, 582L, 
590L, 592L, 593L, 597L, 599L, 601L, 602L, 612L, 618L, 622L, 632L, 
634L, 635L, 637L, 650L, 651L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 665L, 666L, 
668L, 671L, 672L, 675L, 684L, 686L, 693L, 697L, 705L, 708L, 719L, 
725L, 726L, 730L, 733L, 734L, 752L, 756L, 777L, 785L, 789L, 791L, 
796L, 797L, 799L, 800L, 802L, 807L, 808L, 810L, 813L, 814L), 
    nPhotosClassified = c(113L, 164L, 2126L, 637L, 75L, 16L, 
    161L, 29L, 15L, 6338L, 596L, 18L, 14L, 63L, 36777L, 19117L, 
    5625L, 584L, 3477L, 541L, 6L, 6L, 112L, 8L, 5L, 290L, 120L, 
    12L, 9L, 2675L, 9L, 4L, 657L, 149L, 151L, 8L, 4104L, 285L, 
    192L, 734L, 5L, 129L, 155L, 11L, 516L, 410L, 55L, 1L, 581L, 
    293L, 28L, 17810L, 2690L, 5L, 587L, 359L, 9L, 493L, 404L, 
    21L, 3L, 2L, 91L, 23L, 3L, 728L, 29L, 1540L, 10556L, 1L, 
    54L, 905L, 25L, 22L, 1L, 14L, 16L, 13L, 10L, 21L, 121L, 7870L, 
    53L, 1777L, 11L, 850L, 35L, 635L, 7L, 5728L, 1972L, 3613L, 
    16L, 51L, 131L, 77L, 267L, 718L, 11L, 18L, 5088L, 113L, 48L, 
    302L, 33L, 44L, 20L, 22L, 7L, 30L, 8L, 69L, 4L, 11L, 2428L, 
    3131L, 2459L, 12L, 150L, 21L, 702L, 10L, 23L, 38L, 1L, 1L, 
    24L, 10L, 6L, 1443L, 221L, 4363L, 27L, 46L, 9L, 8L, 10633L, 
    56L, 38L, 20L, 171L, 36L, 5L, 3L, 108L, 10L, 559L, 83L, 60L, 
    3L, 9L, 697L, 100L, 27L, 114L, 186L, 8127L, 10L, 58L, 76L, 
    472L, 6L, 72L, 3748L, 130L, 9L, 2459L, 80L, 468L, 198L, 4L, 
    108L, 35L, 10L, 310L, 207L, 499L, 20L, 32L, 1178L, 730L, 
    999L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 178L, 4L, 31L, 16L, 1592L, 385L, 
    73L, 698L, 4L, 42L, 90L, 772L, 509L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 36L, 987L, 
    395L, 15L, 23194L, 16L, 956L, 15L, 5614L, 3L, 1700L, 74L, 
    65L, 18L, 389L, 35L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 1271L, 12L, 80L, 117L, 356L, 
    3L, 59L, 85L, 382L, 8L, 6L, 33L, 5L, 119L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("person_id", "nPhotosClassified"
), row.names = c(NA, -236L))
```

Comment: use `geom_histogram(center = 1)` to set the boundaries at integers

Comment: Or maybe `boundary = 1`.  Can you add an example dataset to your question?

Comment: Thanks @Nate and @aosmith. `center = 1` didn't change anything, while `boundary = 1` made the edges *very* close to the tick marks, but you can see it overshooting by a tiny bit. What's the best way for me to add a dataset to the question???

Comment: use `dput(nPhotosClassified)` and paste in that result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I thought using the `breaks` argument to be the most straightforward way to think about this, mostly due to the complication of an x scale transformation.

The histogram bin `breaks` need to ultimately be set on the transformed scale.  This translates to setting the histogram breaks on the scale of `log10(nPhotosClassified)`.

The breaks depends on the range of `log10(nPhotosClassified)`.

```
with(nPhotosClassified, range(log10(nPhotosClassified)) )

[1] 0.000000 4.565576
```

So the breaks need to go from 0 to 5.  You wanted these evenly spaced between integers (i.e., 2 bins per 10^integer), so we want a break every 0.5 units.

```
ggplot(data = nPhotosClassified, mapping = aes(x = nPhotosClassified)) + 
     geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 5, by = .5) ) + 
     scale_x_log10(name = "Number of photos classified",
                   breaks = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000))
```

[image]

There may be a less manual way to do this, but the other arguments to control the histogram bins, like `boundary`, didn't seem to translate well with scale transformation.